# Drawer.Navigator Props not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, navigation-drawer, webstorm

I'm just doing a course on React Native, and can't get any of the props to work using Drawer Navigator. I'm using iOS Simulator (14.3) on Mac M1, with WebStorm IDE. I'm also using bare React Native, not Expo.

I've attached my App.js code below. As you will see, it's very basic, but initialRouteName is the only prop that works. None of the others do what they are expected to do. The app doesn't crash, the props just don't change the behaviour as expected.

As far as I understand, these props are supported in iOS.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

// screen code held in separate .js files
import ScreenA from "./ScreenA";
import ScreenB from "./ScreenB";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function App() {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        
        initialRouteName={'Screen B'} // works fine
        drawerPosition={"right"} // not working
        drawerType={'front'} // not working
        edgeWidth={800} // not working
        hideStatusBar={true} // not working
        overlayColor={'#000000'} // not working
        drawerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#56cb6a' // not working
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name={'Screen A'}
                       component={ScreenA}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name={'Screen B'}
                       component={ScreenB}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: I seem to have got this working using screenOptions instead of Drawer.Navigator props. Maybe Drawer.Navigator props have been deprecated since the tutorial?

```
screenOptions={{
          drawerPosition: 'right',
          drawerType: 'front', 
          swipeEdgeWidth: 200, 
          headerShown: false, 
          overlayColor: '#00000050', 
          drawerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#dee0e8',
            width: 225
          },
          swipeEnabled: true, 
        }}
```